# App to create a Video from an MP3 File and GIF Picture(s)?

Tags: software-recommendation, video, encoding

Is there a an app that allows me to create a Video from an MP3 file (as Audio stream) and one, or more Pictures, such as GIF, PNG, JPG (animated or not)?

So far I've found Pitivi, which appears to do the Job, however the Video always seems to be rather long... around 13 Minutes, to be specific.
Kino doesn't appear to allow input / import of MP3 or raw Pictures, and Avidemux doesn't seem to be able to create "new" videos.

A windows Application would be fine too, as long as it runs with wine, and doesn't charge money...

UPDATE:

I've tried PiTiVi, but as mentioned before, it keeps adding additional "silent minutes" to the resulting video, which is usually uo to 13 minutes.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what your problem with Pitivi is?

Comment: @Bobby `however the Video always seems to be rather long... around 13 Minutes, to be specific` ...

Comment: @nebukadnezzar: Yes...but I can't understand that sentence. Do you mean that every video you create/export/save is longer then the project itself?

Comment: @Bobby: exactly.

Comment: @nebukadnezzar Please update your original question with the information so it doesn't get lost in the comments.

Comment: @Jorge Castro: There isn't really need to update the question as there is nothing to add...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Imagination](http://imagination.sourceforge.net/) should do the trick. To install it, [click here](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/imagination).

Comment: Works like a charme. Half of my rep are yours now :-)

Comment: Glad it was useful to you!

Comment: BTW imagination is part of the Universe repositories. Nice find.

Answer (score 7):

I'd probably do it the hard way! I'd break the gif into frames and then reconstruct it with an audio track. Sounds hard but how's this:

```
convert input.gif input%05d.jpg
ffmpeg -r 5 -i input%05d.jpg -i audio.mp3 -acodec copy  -y -an -map 0:0 -map 1:0 ouput.avi
```

Alter the `-r 5` argument to change the framerate of gif video.

`ffmpeg` can handle animated gifs but it struggles with the framerate and colours. It's much happier with jpegs. It's a big tool that few people fully understand (I'm still learning) but it's very powerful.

Comment: "Number of stream maps must match number of output streams" when using `ffmpeg -i image.png -i audio.mp3  -acodec copy  -y -an -map 0:0 -map 0:0 ouput.avi` .. i'm not very familiar with ffmpeg, though.

Comment: ffmpeg -loop_input -shortest -i toors.mp3 -i Pobrane/IMG_0112a.JPG -ab 128k output.avi

This one worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I use Avidemux, it can import images, the trick is not to make a new video, but open the first image in the sequence.

Name the images sequentially like 001.png, 002.png, 003.png etc. Opening the first one will import the others in after it.

Use the video menu to set the frame rate, choose your audio source, and take it from there.

It supports [.jpg and .png](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avidemux#Supported_formats), so best to convert to those formats first. [Phatch](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/phatch) is one such batch image conversion tool.

Answer (score 1):

Try SMILE http://www.getdeb.net/app/Smile.

I have tried it some month ago and my impression was good, despite it's not a mature program. Unfortunately now the official site of SMILE give a sad 404 error message and it's also not packaged for Ubuntu.

Another interesting software for creating slideshow is [Videoporama](http://www.videoporama.tuxfamily.org/).
It's written in Python and Qt and it's quite similar to imagination.

Videoporama develop is very active and it improve constantly.
You can read an (italian) [article that illustrates some new features](http://www.anxurweb.com/videoporama-0-8-1-rilaciata-una-nuova-versione-con-interessanti-novita.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20anxur%20%28Anxur%20Web%29).

Comment: The screenshots of Videoporama and Smile look very promising, unfortunately I don't speak a single word french... Especially Smile seems to lack a Translation :-( I'm going to vote this up nevertheless, due to nice finds. :-)

Comment: Videoporama has stopped to be developed. Its successor is ffdiaporama: http://ffdiaporama.tuxfamily.org/fr/index.php