# How to loop an animated GIF file as a background of a music?

Tags: 22.04, video, ffmpeg, music, gif

I have a GIF file which is 5 seconds long, and an mp3 which is about 3 minutes long.

I want to create a video where the GIF file will be the background animation (replayed repeatedly), and the mp3 audio will play.

How to do this with ffmpeg or some other tool in Ubuntu?

---

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8976/app-to-create-a-video-from-an-mp3-file-and-gif-pictures?noredirect=1&lq=1), but the command `convert` destroyed the color of the GIF, and the final video did not have any sound. Another answer mentions the software Imagination, but I could not figure out how to use it. I am looking for an answer that works for a recent version of Ubuntu, like 22.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic way to do it would be:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i input.gif -i audio.mp3 -shortest output.mp4
```

where `-stream_loop -1` means looping the following input infinitely, while `-shortest` ends the loop when the shortest (audio) stream ends. `-fflags shortest` can also be added to ensure no extra length in some situations. The rest should be self-explantatory - input and output names.